# hbase: error in starting master

Tags: hbase

I'm getting the following error while starting the hbase master:

**java.net.BindException: Problem binding to /67.215.65.132:60000 : Cannot assign requested address**

does anyone know what's wrong with hbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and posting if someone else is facing the same error on SUSE Linux just disable the IPv6, as the hbase reverse dns the hostname to get the ip.